# What is the meaning of "if test $# = 1" and "if test -f $1"

Tags: command-line

What is the meaning of  `if test $# = 1` and `if test -f $1`?

Comment: You should start self-learning with http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html

Comment: Questions about [bash are not off topic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13807/are-bash-shell-scripting-questions-on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

- `$# = 1`:

  If number of argument passed to the script is equal to one.
- `-f $1`:

  If the entered parameter is a regular file and exists.

---

Read [more](https://www.mylinuxplace.com/bash-special-variables/):

```
man test
```

Comment: Using `test` explicitly is fairly rare these days.

Comment: Worth noting that `=` performs string comparison, not numeric. Although in this case it won't be an issue ( `$#` is always numeric ), it could lead to a person learning scripting get into bad habit of misusing `=` operator, and where another variable `$var` holding arbitrary data is compared with literal, well that could be an issue.

Comment: `man test` displays the manpage of the external `test` command, but `bash` and presumably most other shells have their own `test` builtin; `help test` displays the help for the latter.